# How do I move partition in ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I've been trying to add Free Space to my Ubuntu Files system using Gparted as follows,

[image]

But when I right click on sda10 and choose Move/Resize option, I am not able to expand sda10 into unallocated space as follows,

[image]

I've also tried to copy sda10 and place it before the unallocated space, but that option is disabled when I right click.

Answer (score 3):

Gparted indicates that your `ext4` partition is mounted. You cannot move it, when it is mounted.

You should **boot the computer from another drive**, for example an Ubuntu install drive (USB or DVD or memory card), and check that your `ext4` partition is unmounted. Then Gparted will allow you to edit it (move and or resize). You can unmount the partition with the `umount`command before starting Gparted but also within Gparted.

In a similar way the swap partition can be released with the `swapoff` command to make it possible to edit (move and or resize). It can be swapped off within Gparted too.

---

The key icons in Gparted indicate that the partitions are locked.