# Why am I unable to allocate more free space to the root file system?

Tags: partitioning, docker

My root file system has recently become full, and I was hoping to allocate some more space to it. In the picture linked below, Partition 5 is my root file system, but I am unable to add the 78G that I have free to it. I have tried booting from a usb drive and modifying it through the build in disk utility, but that it just would only let me decrease size. I am aware the picture says there is memory available, but this was after I nuked docker images and reinstalled it. It is currently at no space available.

Alternatively, is there a way I can make docker user memory from my filesystem with more memory?

Current Partition Allocations:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to move Partition 6 so that the free space is before it instead of after it.  Then the free space should be next to Partition 5 allowing for you to resize Partition 5.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Is there a utility that I could utilize to do that?

Comment: Live Boot disk with `gparted` on it can do it.  You just really want to make sure that no partitions are mounted before you move them.  Also, it is a good practice to back up your data before moving or messing with partitions.  The risk of data loss can be great when performing changes like these.

Comment: Also see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011722/how-do-i-move-partition-in-ubuntu

Comment: Is your computer a recent UEFI machine, or an older BIOS machine? I notice that your NVme is in MBR format, and it probably should be GPT. Please answer that, and show me a screenshot of `gparted`, and I can make a better recommendation. Are your other SSDs also in MBR format? Also, have you checked for firmware updates for your SSDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I apologize for the lateness, your answer worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: If you've got a recent UEFI computer, your SSDs/HDD should be in GPT format.

**Note**: From Windows, download `Samsung Magician` from [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/), and check the firmware in your Samsung SSDs.

---

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda6 partition all the way right
- **resize** /dev/sda5 right side all the way right
- click the Apply icon